# What's the grammatical structure of 这是你第一次来中国吗？

Tags: sentence-structure, number

I am confused about the sentence 这是你第一次来中国吗？
I think I know the correct translation: "Is this the first time you go to China?"
However, I am confused about the grammatical structure of the sentence.

I would expect that when the structure 这是 (something) 吗？is present, then (something) is a noun phrase. For example:

- 这是你要的吗？(Is this what you want?)
- 这是你点的菜吗？(Is this the dish you ordered?)

你要的 (what you want) and 你点的菜 (the dish you ordered) are noun phrases (right?). However, I can't identify 你第一次来中国 as a noun phrase.

If 你第一次来中国 is a noun phrase: What is the structure that makes it a noun phrase? Why does it not say 你的第一次来中国? Isn't 次 a measure word? Why can it be followed by a verb?

If 你第一次来中国 is not a noun phrase, how can it be used with 这是 (something) 吗？?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put. There is always S V O structure in Chinese.

In this case, 这(this) is the S, 是(is) is the V, 你第一次来中国 (your first time coming to China) is the object phrase.

PS 你第一次来中国 = 你的第一次来中国. (The 的 in the first sentence got dropped)

Answer (score 1):

**这是你第一次来中国吗？** means `Is this your first time in China?`

I wouldn't consider this a *noun phrase* at all...

`第一次` as a whole is an **adverb**.

`来` is your **verb**.

Everything else is pretty self-explanatory and you seem to understand the other parts of the sentence.

In fact you can use **这是你第一次** as a set phrase to ask `is this your first time xxx` while just adding `xxx` at the end.